# Connect PC to SQLite db located in windows ce storage

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, windows-ce

I have a SQLite database file in my PC. I have an offline application on my Windows CE. This app gets data from this file and updates them. The process is here:

1- initialize SQLite db file (**in PC**)

2- Copy db file to windows CE storage (**in PC**)

3- Some process on data (**in Windows CE**)

4- Copy db file to PC (in order to access the data) (**in PC**)

5- Do main app processes (**in PC**)

After a while the db records become large. I used indices and `vacuum` command on db and the problem solved.

Again after a while the db records become huge. Now copying the file takes long time. I want to remove steps 2 and 4 in order to speed up Get/Send events in PC app.

Connection string is my problem. Here is my code:

```
private string ConnectionString_SQLite = "";
public SQLite_()
    {
        string Data_Source_SQLite = `@"\\\Asset\System.db"`;
        ConnectionString_SQLite = "Data Source=" + Data_Source_SQLite + ";Version=3;";
    }
```

I tested these data sources in connection string:

- `@"\Asset\System.db"`
- `@"\\Asset\System.db"`
- `@"\\\Asset\System.db"`
- `@"Computer\POINTMOBILE PM60\\\Asset\System.db"` (copied from windows explorer address bar)

Is there anyway to access the file located in path `\\Asset\`?